# Umbrello UML tool not opening

Tags: uml

I'm using version of Ubuntu 13.10 and I install Umbrello tool for UML diagrams. But the problem is when I click on the icon its not opening. When I open it using terminal like:

```
$ umbrello
```

Its give me error:

```
umbrello(5801)/kdeui (kdelibs): Attempt to use QAction "edit_undo" with KXMLGUIFactory! 
umbrello(5801)/kdeui (kdelibs): Attempt to use QAction "edit_redo" with KXMLGUIFactory! 
umbrello(5801) UMLListView::findView: could not find  "class diagram"  in  UMLListViewItem: "Logical View", type="lvt_Logical_View", id="Logical View", children=1 
umbrello(5801) UMLListView::findView: could not find  "class diagram"  in  UMLListViewItem: "Logical View", type="lvt_Logical_View", id="Logical View", children=1
```

I don't know how to launch it. Any one know about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across the same problem and here is the solution

```
sudo umbrello --geometry 600x400+0+0
```

and that should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been fixed, see  https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=329831 for details

Answer (score 0):

First just try to open from dash.

open your dash ans search for umbrello

[image]

If it doesn't open then try to purge

```
sudo apt-get purge umbrello
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get install umbrello
```

and try again

Comment: Again the same problem.Not opening

Comment: What is the error?! same as above?!

Comment: When I click on its icon, no reply.Icon just blink and then do nothing. When I open through terminal , the error mention above.